# Как посчитать из массива количество элементов php

Tags: php

Вот не могу решить задачу. Надо посчитать элементы массива на изображении как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключи массива можно считать внутренние данные не нужны. Но таких массивов может быть много и вложенности массивов тоже. Как реализовать?

Comment: Для начала корректно задать вопрос.

Comment: Ну вот не знаю как вам задать. Надо посчитать вложенные элементы массива у которых есть childs. Например на изображении у 24 элемента есть 2 потомка 25 и 26. а таких вложенностей может быть много

Comment: В тексте вопроса укажите, что должно получиться при подсчете вот по этому примеру на картинке и поясните почему получено именно такое значение

Comment: Mike, эти данные взяты из базы мне нужно лишь посчитать внутренние элементы массива childs и все. Но не знаю как это сделать

Comment: если это взято из базы то может и решить это следует на стороне базы, а не вытаскивать в пхп?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте

```
count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php

> Если необязательный параметр mode установлен в COUNT_RECURSIVE (или
>   1), count() будет рекурсивно подсчитывать количество элементов
>   массива. Это особенно полезно для подсчёта всех элементов многомерных
>   массивов.

Или используйте рекурсию, если только childs нужно подсчитать, что-то вроде этого

```
function count_array($array, $sum = 0){
    foreach($array as $k){
        $sum++;
        if(!empty($k['childs']) && is_array($k['childs'])){ 
            $sum += count_array($k['childs']); 
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за изложенный ответ)